# Windows pre-boot UEFI specification, how to detect touch devices

Tags: c++, windows, uefi

We are making some product changes in our Windows UEFI pre-boot environment. However the changes are specific to touch devices and should not be executed on a normal machine (laptop or desktop) that doesn't have a touch screen.

I am using the UEFI specification listed here: http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_3_1.pdf

So far I have been unable to differentiate between a touch device and a non-touch device using the API's documented in the UEFI specification. Any help on how to differentiate touch devices will be appreciated.

Please let me know if you need any additional info. Thanks.

Comment: Is your touch device attached via USB or Serial port, how would you normally detect your device? Can you elaborate on Windows UEFI pre-boot environment changes, where is your code located and when does it run? Is it UEFI or Windows code?